# Replace of - with 0(Zero) at any position

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column value with - at any position in my table.I just want to replace with 0. How is it possible with regexp_repace and with only replace function.

```
Table Name - ABC

 Column1
row 1 qw-ty34io-99
row 2 1ere45-09877-
row 3 we455-e45rt6
```

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function should do the trick:

```
UPDATE abc
SET    column1 = REPLACE(column1, '-', '0');
```

Comment: Why would you use suboptimal regular expressions instead of simple & effective REPLACE?

Comment: If you really want to, it's `regexp_replace(column1,'-','0')`.